Inheritance in US & UK
US citizen currently living in UK. If I gain inheritance thru US family, what will the tax implications be?
Am trying to see if it’ll be better off to move back to US or not!
Thanks

AFAIK both in the UK and in the US inheritance/estate tax is paid from the estate. So, are you asking where it's better to die tax-wise? If you anticipate your estate to be above threshold, I suggest you talk to an estate attorney.

Thanks. Not asking if I die, but if I inherit, would it be better to be based in US and inherit US estate or stay in UK and inherit US estate

Estate tax is on the estate, not on you. It doesn't matter where you are.

Based on this website/Q&A you would not have to pay any inheritance tax if you live in the UK and the deceased had no UK based assets.  If they had some UK based assets, then you would pay the tax on those and they would be quite high, 40% after a fairly low exemption (£325,000, ~418K USD).
The US estate tax rate can go to 40%, but only once the estate exceeds a large exemption (around 13 million), and is graduated above that.
Some US states also have estate/inheritance tax but not many.
